# Read CSV file each two characters

Tags: python, csv

I have a file that looks like that :

200 310 201 310 202 310...

Basically, these are pixel coordinates grouped. So for example, pixel number 1 is (200x310). 
Now, I would like too loop over each pixel. I've started by loading the file

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    #Now I would like to have something like :
    for i in ???
         x,y = ???
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the pixels all on one line, or is it one line per pair?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a straightforward approach would be better:

```
for i in range(0,len(spamreader),2):
   x, y = spamreader[i], spamreader[i + 1]
```

Is that something like that that you are seeking for ?

EDIT : This doesn't work. According to the documentation, you could do something like that :

```
while(true):
    try:
        x = spamreader.next() #.next() returns the next element as a string
        y = spamreader.next() # same
        # do stuff with it...
     except StopIteration:
        # we have read everything
```

Comment: fwiw, I get `TypeError: object of type '_csv.reader' has no len()` when I try that

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation right now, hold on

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s2,s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    a = iter(iterable)
    for pair in zip(a, a):
        yield pair

with open('myfile.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        for pair in pairwise(line.split()):
            print(pair)
```

Output given the line of input in your question:

```
('200', '310')
('201', '310')
('202', '310')
```

In Python 3, you could use a `yield from` and simplify `pairwise()` a little:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s2,s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    a = iter(iterable)
    yield from zip(a, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply chain the rows returned by the csv reader and use the values in pairs

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    items = itertools.chain.from_iterable((row for row in spamreader))
    for i in items:
        x, y = i, next(items) # the next consumes a second element
```

As the `next` function does consume a second element, on each iteration you actually get the next 2 elements